# Xcode Interface resizes itself, loses Assistant

Tags: xcode

I recently upgraded to Xcode 12.3 and have run into some nuisances that I did not experience with an older version.

1. When switching from an open tab showing storyboard and the Assistant to another tab, then back to the original, Xcode resizes the Storyboard and assistant windows, and centers Storyboard at a different place than what I had been working on (I thought the center of the storyboard, but that doesn't appear to be the case).

   Is there a way to prevent this so that when I return it looks exactly as I had left it?
2. Occasionally, when switching to different tabs, when I return to Storyboard, the assistant window no longer has that class for the object selected in Storyboard, but instead has the message "No Assistant Results".  The only way I have found to get it back is to close and reload Xcode.

   Is this a bug or is there a way for me to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest filing a radar. [Link](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)